# React: Mapping a component with local storage data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently creating a history list component for a form in a react app and am having some trouble with the local storage.

Essentially, I want the app to render a list of past inputs from the user's local storage data. My current idea is based in duplicating the local storage data is a state variable.

```
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);
```

On form submit I call this function with the form input as the parameter (the input is a single string)

```
const setLocalStorage = (input) => {
        const hist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history')) || [];
        console.log(hist)
        hist.push(input)
        localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(hist))
        setHistory(hist);
    }
```

This is meant to put the history from local story into `hist`, push the input that was just submitted into the existing array `hist`, and update the local storage with the new value. The state variable should then be updated with the most updated array of strings with the `setHistory(hist)` call.

Also, I want local storage to be pulled on first render so I can use that data to render the history list on initial load. I have a useEffect hook for this as shown:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setHistory(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history')))
        console.log(history)
    }, []);
```

The problem I'm facing is that the state never seems to get updated? I can instead do a console log for `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history'))` and get the local storage array returned but this of course isn't helpful for data usage. I know that the local storage is properly being pulled from this but I'm unable to update the state for some reason. I need the state updated so I can conditionally render and use the array for mapping each item on the history list. When I console log "history" I get an empty array.

**TL;DR**

Concisely, what is the cleanest method to have local storage and state values maintain equivalency? Hope my post was clear enough to understand!

I'm remaking and updating a regular JS app on React for practice so I'm able to provide a live link of how I want this simple component to work.

https://giovannimalcolm.github.io/weather-dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

The second returned parameter of `useState` is similar to the `this.setState` which is asynchronous. You may see that state is not changed even `setHistory` is called. Passing function instead of the value will avoid this issue as it will be executed after the state is updated. This might be useful for better understanding [Passing function to setState()](https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/content/patterns/27.passing-function-to-setState.html)

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const hist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history'))
    setHistory(prevHistory => [...prevHistory, ...hist])
}, []);
```